# BlockRandom and NestList: how get random maps with the same noise?

Tags: random

I need to compare solutions in random systems with the same noise and different initial conditions.

Here I run twice a random map with the same initial condition, inside a `BlockRandom`. The output expected should be exactly the same orbit but they are different.

What have I done wrong?

```
map[x_, α_] := α/2 ArcTan[x] + 1/2 x

ClearAll[α]
noisymap[x_, α_, σ_] := map[x, α] + σ RandomReal[{-1, 1}]

ClearAll[noisy1, noisy2]
BlockRandom[
    noisy1 = NestList[With [{α = 2, σ = 0.1}, noisymap[#, α, σ] &], -0.32, 1000];
    noisy2 = NestList[With [{α = 2, σ = 0.1}, noisymap[#, α, σ] &], -0.32, 1000];
]

ListLinePlot[{noisy1, noisy2}]

ListLinePlot[Abs[noisy1 - noisy2]]
```

Comment: Add a `SeedRandom[<some same value>]` before each, should be peachy.

Comment: Simple mistake: use *two separate* `BlockRandom`s, one for each definition. (And without producing any random numbers or reseeding the RNGs in between.)

Answer (score 3):

`BlockRandom` simply isolates anything affecting random number generation, etc. that is changed (like seeding). If you do nothing, there's nothing to isolate, and if you do nothing, the results will be the same as outside such a block: the second list gets subsequent random variates from the stream.

Use `SeedRandom` like so (snippet of your code modified):

```
map[x_, α_] := α/2 ArcTan[x] + 1/2 x

ClearAll[α]
noisymap[x_, α_, σ_] := 
 map[x, α] + σ RandomReal[{-1, 1}]

ClearAll[noisy1, noisy2]
BlockRandom[

 SeedRandom[1];
 noisy1 = 
  NestList[With[{α = 2, σ = 0.1}, 
    noisymap[#, α, σ] &], -0.32, 1000];
 SeedRandom[1];
 noisy2 = 
  NestList[With[{α = 2, σ = 0.1}, 
    noisymap[#, α, σ] &], -0.32, 1000];]

noisy1 == noisy2

(* True *)
```

If you want both to just have same noise that differs each run, substitute some random value for the `SeedRandom` of both, or generate noise once and add to both.

Here's an example of `BlockRandom` behavior:

```
(* set some seed*)
SeedRandom[1];
list1 = RandomInteger[10, 10];
Print["First ten with seed 1 is: ", list1];

(*reset seed, so stream will be *the same*)
SeedRandom[1];

(* get first five *)
list2 = RandomInteger[10, 5];
Print["First five with seed 1 is: ", list2]

(* make a block *)
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[1]; list3 = RandomInteger[10, 10];
 Print["First ten with seed 1 in block: ", list3]]

(* we're out of block...*)
list4 = RandomInteger[10, 5];
Print["Next five from original stream: ", list4];

(*
First ten with seed 1 is: {1,4,0,7,0,0,8,6,0,4}
First five with seed 1 is: {1,4,0,7,0}
First ten with seed 1 in block: {1,4,0,7,0,0,8,6,0,4}
Next five from original stream: {0,8,6,0,4}
*)
```

Note how the variates *within the block* are *completely* independent from what's happening "outside": when we leave the block, the behavior and state pick up where we left off. This includes seeding, setting of generator type, etc.

Comment: @anna: of course you get the same results. That's expected. `BlockRandom` is for when you want to *isolate* some changes you make to the state of *MMA*'s "random objects" that you *don't* want to be seen outside of the blocked code, like say you needed super-quality numbers via mersenne twister (slower generation) for some operation: you could `BlockRandom`, tell *MMA* to use mersenne, when the block is left, *MMA* reverts to whatever was in use before (*Incuding* all prior state(s)). I'll add an example to my answer, might help you...

Comment: thanks, I'll wait for the example. Just to clarify:
fixing the seed, do I  generate the same succession of random reals  for both maps (which is what I want to do) or 
 the same random real number at each step? 

(and why doesn't stackexcange alert me when an answer is posted?)

Comment: @anna: Yes, when you use `SeedRandom` with some value, the calls to random generators will return the same stream, so you'd either seed with the same value before generating the noise for each, or more efficiently, generate the noise once and add to each list. No idea why you don't get notified...

Comment: thanks for the example

Comment: FWIW, I think your explanation is wrong. @anna's surprise that `BlockRandom` didn't do what she expected seems warranted, except that she ought to have wrapped the definitions of `noisy1` and `noisy2` in *separate* `BlockRandom`s.

Comment: @OleksandrR.: Care to illuminate? There's nothing wrong with my explanation that I can see, wrapping each separately just does the same thing - maintains state outside of the block. Not to mention simply asserting doing so guarantees the same results is silly, unless you *know* *nothing* has changed state between such uses. The correct way is to seed with same, and isolate that with `BlockRandom` if isolation of that action is warranted.

Comment: I was referring more to your comment than to the answer as such. There is no (strict) need to seed the RNG in order to get repeatable results, although several times you imply otherwise. All that one must do is ensure that all random numbers are generated inside `BlockRandom`s originating from the same `$RandomState`. (Okay, `$RandomState` is no longer enough to encapsulate all RNG state, hence why we have `BlockRandom` in the first place. But this is just a technicality owing to the inclusion of several library RNGs in recent *Mathematica* versions.)

Comment: To be more explicit, the only things that can change the RNG state are: 1. generating a random number; 2. reseeding the generator; 3. choosing a new RNG algorithm. So if you don't do any of these things in between separate `BlockRandom`s, the results will be perfectly repeatable. The only caveat and the reason why seeding is probably a good idea is that one may not know where random numbers are generated un-`Block`ed in the code of *Mathematica* itself. But that doesn't apply to this scenario since the `BlockRandom`s directly follow each other, with no other code in between.

Comment: @OleksandrR.:Frankly, you're grasping at straws. As I said, unless one *knows absolutely* that *nothing* has changed the underlying state, it is plain *sloppy* to assert otherwise. The intricacies of *when* state changes (many are surprised using `RandomSample` changes state, e.g.) what with internals changing state (Monte-Carlo method in use, anyone?) make it rational to *assume* something has clobbered state, and to properly block & seed or just seed to get guaranteed repeatable results. If you choose to argue this further, please move to chat.

Comment: I can't ping you in the chat. So this will be my last comment here and we will continue elsewhere.